# In Settlers 2 (PC), is it possible to get food back from an exhausted mine or otherwise prevent food waste?

Tags: the-settlers-2

I started playing Settlers 2 on PC and got a message that one of my coal mines was exhausted.

I can see that people are still delivering food into it though, but since the mine has no resources, it does not consume any food and it seems that any further input food will be wasted and disappear when I destroy the exhausted mine.

Is this correct or is there any way to get the food back? Or to prevent them from filling up food in a mine that cannot use it? Seems like an oversight from the developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short and simple answer is no: it is not possible to retrieve food that has been placed in a mine.

Another way to reduce waste that I learned through playing is to not produce all 3 kinds of food. I personally found pig farming unnecessary since it uses the same input ingredients as baking bread (grain and water) so I don't see the point of doing it.

Also, a few guides that I read have suggested that fishing is not efficient either, and I can somewhat agree with that after the beginning of a game since fisheries run out quickly and need to be rebuilt elsewhere.

So by only producing bread and no other food, we can never lose more than 2 pieces of food in a single mine, which effectively reduces the waste without the micromanagement of destroying them right away when they are empty.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to deal with this is to destroy the mine as soon as it is exhausted. You'll lose any food inside it but food on its way will be sent to other mines or returned to storehouses.

You'll lose a small amount of food but it's not a big problem. Meat and bread are unlimited and 2 per mine is a tiny percentage of late-game food production.